# wro4j less-compiler compiles .css files, too

Tags: wro4j

I am using wro4j 1.7.3 with less4j/lessCSS-compiler.

```
preProcessors=less4j,
yuiCssMin,googleClosureSimple
```

In my wro.xml, I have something like:

```
<group name='css'>
    <css>/resources/css/base.css</css>
</group>
```

When compiling, I will get a error because wro4j treats my *.css-file also as a *.less-file.

```
Exception occured while processing: ro.isdc.wro.WroRuntimeException: 
Could not compile    less. 1 error(s) occured:
ERROR 437:1 missing EOF at '}' in stylesheet (which started at 23:1)
, class: ro.isdc.wro.WroRuntimeException,caused by:     
com.github.sommeri.less4j.Less4jException Could not compile less. 1 error(s) occured:
ERROR 437:1 missing EOF at '}' in stylesheet (which started at 23:1)
```

When using lessCSS, instead of less4j, the error reason is better shown:

```
MEZ: [ERROR] Exception occured while processing: ro.isdc.wro.WroRuntimeException: Could  
not execute the script because: 
{
"type": "Runtime",
"message": "error evaluating function `saturate`: Cannot find function toHSL in object   
[object Object].",
"filename": null,
"index": 11114.0,
"line": 754.0,
"callLine": null,
"callExtract": null,
"stack": null, 
"column": 17.0,
"extract": [
".img-saturate{ ",
"   -webkit-filter: saturate(500%);",
"   -moz-filter: saturate(500%);"
]
}, class: ro.isdc.wro.WroRuntimeException,caused by:  Could not execute the script   
because: 
{
"type": "Runtime",
"message": "error evaluating function `saturate`: Cannot find function toHSL in   
object [object Object].",
"filename": null,
"index": 11114.0,
"line": 754.0,
"callLine": null,
"callExtract": null,
"stack": null,
"column": 17.0,
"extract": [
".img-saturate{ ",
"   -webkit-filter: saturate(500%);",
"   -moz-filter: saturate(500%);"
] 
}
```

Changing the processor-order does not help:

```
preProcessors=yuiCssMin,googleClosureSimple
postProcessors=less4j
```

The error still exists.

Is there a possibility, to say wro4j, that it should not treat files endings with css as less.

Comment: Could you provide the content of the base.css file? The exception is saying that toHSL function cannot be found. Where is it defined?

Comment: I have not any function in base.css. I have no "toHSL"-function in base.css. Base.css is only a "pure" css-file without any less-syntax. However, the compiler of less is complaining about the following css-class: .img-saturate{ 
 -webkit-filter: saturate(500%);
 -moz-filter: saturate(500%);
 -o-filter: saturate(500%);
 -ms-filter: saturate(500%);
 filter: saturate(500%);
}. When deleting this css-class, then all works fine. However, I guess, the problem lies in the fact, that wro4j scanns and treats pure css-files also as less-files. The less-compiler should ignore files ending with *.css.

Comment: The less-compiler thinks that saturate() is a less-defined function. However, it is not. It s a css-function.

Comment: By default a processor is applied to all resources. If you want less4j processor to be applied only to resourcess with less extension, replace the less4j alias with less4j.less

Comment: I guess, it does not matter usin less4j.less as pre or postprocessor.

Comment: Actually it does matter. The file extension information is available for pre processors. When post processor is applied, there is no extension info since a merged resources is processed. However, if you want to apply less4j only to a certain resources or group, you can customize it using something similar to http://code.google.com/p/wro4j/wiki/ProcessorDecorators

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks Alex,

by using less4j.less, the less-processor will only scan less-files:

```
preProcessors=less4j, yuiCssMin,googleClosureSimple
#postProcessors=less4j
```

However, afterwards I found the real reason for the error. A ending brace was missing in the css file. By adding the brace, all works fine!